# iOS, how to make a custom uibarbuttonitem with no-border, no-span with each other? like this picture?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, uibarbuttonitemstyle

iOS, how to make a custom uibarbuttonitem with no-border, no-span with each other?

like this picture?

[image]

I do not know how to name this style.  all these buttons are on the UIToolBar component.

thank you very much.

Comment: How about a UISegmentedControl subclass?

Comment: UISegmentedControl has a round corner. I am now writing a subclass of UIButton, try to override drawRect: method.

Comment: Do you know how easy it is to get rid of rounded corners in a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding it's better to use segment-controller in such cases, But if you don't wanna use it you can apply the image to your bar buttons in following way.

```
UIImage *image=[[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbuttonimage.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 topCapHeight:10];
// Specify width & height as per your need..

CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width,image.size.height);

UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];

[someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myBarbuttonEvent)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIBarButtonItem *myBarbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=mailbutton;

[someButton release];
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.